# System.DllNotFoundException iTunesMobileDevice.dll

Tags: c#, dll

I try to use the library "mobileDevice". but I get this error: 
it seems that the application does not find the file iTunesMobileDevice.dll.

[image]

in my "Registry Editor" looks like this:

[image]

Things I've tried and did not work:

1). get a file from itunes iTunesMobileDevice.dll 
2). place it in the same directory app

line that probably causes the error:

```
    private static readonly DirectoryInfo ApplicationSupportDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Apple Inc.\Apple Application Support", "InstallDir", Environment.CurrentDirectory).ToString());
    private const string DLLPath = "iTunesMobileDevice.dll";
    private static readonly FileInfo iTunesMobileDeviceFile = new FileInfo(Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Apple Inc.\Apple Mobile Device Support\Shared", "iTunesMobileDeviceDLL", "iTunesMobileDevice.dll").ToString());
```

Comment: Note that there are different directories for your app builds depending on your build target/layout. Usually you'll have Debug builds and Release builds. From your screenshot it looks like you are running the debug build. Did you copy the DLL into the directory with the Debug build of your app?

Comment: @elgonzo I copied only iTunesMobileDevice.dll to C: \ Users \ USER \ Documents \ Visual Studio 2010 \ Projects \ ProjectName \ MobileDevice \ bin \ Debug and to C: \ Users \ USER \ Documents \ Visual Studio 2010 \ Projects \ ProjectName \ Demo \ bin \ Debug. is this you are referring?

Comment: In your screenshot i see that you use SharpDevelop. But the path names you mention here contain "Visual Studio 2010". Are you sure that is the correct path used by the project in SharpDevelop? (could be, i don't know...)

Comment: @elgonzo I copied the whole project to SharpDevelop chub and i get this message: 

There are reference assemblies of the. NET Framework ". NETFramework, Version = v4.5". To resolve this problem, install the SDK or the Compatibility Pack version of ...

Comment: I have tried before to update the version of. NET. but is recognized as the latest version. and do not let me update it.

Comment: Your issue here is not related to an assembly version mismatch (an assembly version mismatch would require the DLL at least to be found, which is not the case here). I would say, use the debugger and set a breakpoint at the code line where you load that iTunesMobileDevice.dll. What is the absolute/full path your code uses there to attempt loading the DLL? (Btw, how would you know that Aaron and not somebody else downvoted your question?)

Comment: @elgonzo I appreciate your time. I will Siguer your advice. but without asking much can you give me an example of how to do it. and about a Votes i saw it on my profil that was him.

Comment: Unfortunately, i am not a user of SharpDevelop, so i cannot really give you sound advice about using its integrated debugger :( (Interesting that you can see user names for the votes on your question. Well, i can't see this information for votes on my answers... and i never asked a question here ;) )

Comment: @manout I didn't downvote you, and I have no insight as to who did. But tell you what, I just put you back to zero with an upvote, so it's like it didn't happen.

Comment: @Aaron Hall sorry for the comment. I have removed and your career has impressed me, I wish more in your career.